# Error: Invalid src prop - next.config.js problem with image component

Tags: javascript, next.js, nextjs-image

I hope you can help me with this issue

im my next.config.js, I have:
`

```
module.exports = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  images: {
    remotePatterns: [
      {
        protocol: 'https',
        hostname: '**.googleapis.com',
        pathname: '/[some folder]/**',
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Yet I get this error:
Error: Invalid src prop ([https://storage.googleapis.com/[some](https://storage.googleapis.com/%5Bsome) folder]/newtest2/DSC_1690.JPG) on `next/image`, hostname "storage.googleapis.com" is not configured under images in your `next.config.js`
See more info: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/next-image-unconfigured-host

, when I use:

```
 <Image
src="https://storage.googleapis.com/[some folder]/newtest2/DSC_1690.JPG"
alt="Picture of the author"
width={250} 
height={250}
  />
```

the file exists.

I´m runnning in dev mode local

I´ve tried alomst anything and combinations on the config file, nothing works. When I use a local file there´s no problem

Comment: Just to try, doest it work with this
     `{
        protocol: 'https',
        hostname: 'storage.googleapis.com',
        pathname: '/[some folder]/**',
      }`

Comment: Hi and thanks. I just tried it and it´s still the same error. Somehow it seems like an issue with the config file and not the image definitions

Comment: hmm, could be a typo issue, you wrote JPG in uppercase for example, did you check this?

Comment: yes, checked that too, but I dont think thats the problem cause it would only give a source error